# Wordpress: Plugin based custom post types

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to make custom post types in my Wordpress site. I started it based on this two articles: [Custom post type](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/), [Site specific plugins](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/what-why-and-how-tos-of-creating-a-site-specific-wordpress-plugin/)

My code is so far:

```
mysite-core.php

<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My awesome site core plugin
Description: Core functions for my site
*/
/* Start Adding Functions Below this Line */

// Our custom post type function
function create_posttype() {

    register_post_type( 'bar',
    // CPT Options
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Bars' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Bar' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'bars'),
        )
    );
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );

/* Stop Adding Functions Below this Line */
?>
```

My question: In the first article there is the part where they give options to the post type:

```
/*
* Creating a function to create our CPT
*/

function custom_post_type() {

// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Movies', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Movie', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Movies', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Movie', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Movies', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Movie', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Movie', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Movie', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Movie', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Movie', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentythirteen' ),
    );

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'movies', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Movie news and reviews', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' ),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */ 
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );

    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'movies', $args );

}

/* Hook into the 'init' action so that the function
* Containing our post type registration is not 
* unnecessarily executed. 
*/

add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

And later:

> Also notice repeated usage of twentythirteen, this is called text
>   domain. If your theme is translation ready and you want your custom
>   post types to be translated, then you will need to mention text domain
>   used by your theme. You can find your theme’s text domain inside
>   style.css file in your theme directory. Text domain will be mentioned
>   in the header of the file.

But my custom post type is plugin based and not theme based. What should I change the `twentythirteen` part? `mysite-core`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__()` function is just a translator. See WP's [function reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/). So, to continue making it translatable, change the text domain (aka `twentythirteen`) to be wherever the translation should be found. In your case `mysite-core`. This is best practice so that your plugin can be internationalized in a standard way. See [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).